# Powershell script to copy publish files from build machine to posting server

Tags: powershell, msbuild, tfsbuild

I am designing TFS build definition to build solution on a build machine and publish files to posting server. I need to copy those publish files directly from build machine to posting server (which is a shared drive that i need to login using credentials).

Till now, we are posting the build results to a shared drive. I have used powershell commands to do this. From there, we are manually updating the files in posting server. Now i am trying to post directly to posting server rather than involving the manual process.

I need a powershell script to

1. Login to posting server
2. Delete the specific files in the posting server
3. Copy publish files from build machine to posting server
4. Logoff from posting server after successful copy

I have got the script to everything except including **user credentials to login** to the destinationpath. I am trying to find some arguments to include login username and password for this destination path, but could not found anything appropriate.

Can this be done using MS Build Arguments instead of script?

Comment: @Daniel Mann, i am trying to find some MS build arguments to do this. I could post it to a different location(a normal shared drive) where there's no need to login... But, i could not find any arguments that i could use to login to the testnet server before posting files

Comment: @Gauty Your question could do with a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post some relevant code so the community can help.

Comment: Why not to use more suitable tools for deployment? You shouldn't copy files manually to the servers. Build should be separated from deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Copy a file to a remote computer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-5.1#examples):

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "Server01" -Credential "Contoso\PattiFul"
Copy-Item "D:\Folder001\test.log" -Destination "C:\Folder001_Copy\" -ToSession $Session
```

Once you type a user name, you will be prompted for a password.